# luaotfload: bug in newest version (26.04.2020)?

Tags: luatex, miktex, luaotfload

I compiled this MWE on two different PCs running MikTeX version 2.9.7400:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}

Some text.

\end{document}
```

It compiles fine on the PC whose MikTeX hasn't been updated in a few days. On the one with up-to-date MikTeX, it generates the error `Font \TU/lmr/m/n/10.95=[lmroman10-regular]:+tlig; at 10.95pt not loadable: metric data not found or bad. \normalsize`

I compared the log files between the two. 
This is the first line of the log with the bug:

```
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.12.0 (MiKTeX 2.9.7400 64-bit)  (format=lualatex 2020.4.26)  26 APR 2020 07:44
```

And here the first line of the log without the bug:

```
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.12.0 (MiKTeX 2.9.7400 64-bit)  (format=lualatex 2020.4.25)  26 APR 2020 07:49
```

Here are the parts of the log file that only appear when the error is triggered:

```
File: scrsize11pt.clo 2020/04/19 v3.30 KOMA-Script font size class option (11pt)

luaotfload | db : Font names database loaded from C:/Users/Anne/AppData/Local/Mi
KTeX/2.9/luatex-cache/generic-dev/names/luaotfload-names.luc
! Font \TU/lmr/m/n/10.95=[lmroman10-regular]:+tlig; at 10.95pt not loadable: met
ric data not found or bad.
<to be read again> 
relax 
l.112 \normalsize

I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.
[Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
You might try inserting a different font spec;
e.g., type `I\font<same font id>=<substitute font name>'.

) (C:/Users/Anne/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.sty
```

and

```
! Arithmetic overflow.
\\typearea ...by100 \divide \ta@temp by\@tempdima 
                                                  \@tempcnta =\ta@temp \ifnu...
l.1738 \typearea[current]{current}

I can't carry out that multiplication or division,
since the result is out of range.


Package typearea Warning: Bad type area settings!
(typearea)                The detected line width is about 27410792%
(typearea)                larger than the heuristically estimated maximum
(typearea)                limit of typographical good line width.
(typearea)                You should e.g. decrease DIV, increase fontsize
(typearea)                or change papersize.

Package: fontenc 2020/02/11 v2.0o Standard LaTeX package
```

and

```
("C:/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg")
! Font \TU/lmr/bx/n/10.95=[lmroman10-bold]:+tlig; at 10.95pt not loadable: metri
c data not found or bad.
<to be read again> 
relax 
l.3955 \strongfontdeclare{ \bfseries }

I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.
[Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
You might try inserting a different font spec;
e.g., type `I\font<same font id>=<substitute font name>'.

))
```

and

```
No file 20200426_luaotfload_bug.aux.
```

I would file a bug report but I don't know where and how. In the meantime, is there a way to install a previous version of `luaotfload`?

Comment: There was no change in luaotfload recently.So I don't think it causing your problem.  I will check in my MiKTeX your example.

Comment: Your example compiles fine for me (MikTeX 2.9 on Win 10, updates just a few minutes ago) with LuaLaTeX.

Comment: Try to delete (or move) the cache: C:/Users/Anne/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/luatex-cache/generic-dev. And as always check for updates in user *and* admin mode.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer deleting the luatex cache solved the problem for the MWE. In the actual file, I am getting another (different) error. I'll try to get to the bottom of that as I suppose that this error caused the luatex cache to be faulty somehow.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in comments.

Comment: @Marijn Fine by me